# this в стрелочной функции при работе с DOM

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять, почему стрелочная функция иначе работает с this.
Простой пример:

```
function btnClick() {
  console.log(this);
};

window.onload = function() {

  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.actions input');
  [...buttons].map((el) => el.onclick = btnClick);

}
//<input type="button" name="save" value="Сохранить">
//<input type="button" name="delete" value="Удалить">
```

При использовании стрелочной функции:

```
const btnClick = () => {
  console.log(this);
};

window.onload = function() {

  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.actions input');
  [...buttons].map((el) => el.onclick = btnClick);

}
//Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}
//Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}
```

Со всеми вытекающими последствиями....
Как быть в данной ситуации? Отказываться от стрелок в пользу Function Declaration? Или все-таки есть решение?

Answer (score 3):

Внутри стрелочной функции используется `this`  контекста (контекст функции или глобальный контекст), в котором она описана. Это и есть их киллерфича, а не более короткий синтаксис. Если тяжело набирать `function funName() { ... }`, то используйте снипетты в вашем текстовом редакторе. Да вот же, первая [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) по запросу "стрелочные функции" с примерами и разъяснениями.

```
 function myFunction () {
     let self = this;
     let functionDeclaration = function () {
         console.log(self === this);
     }

     let arrowFun = () => console.log(self === this);

     functionDeclaration();
     arrowFun();
 }

 myFunction.call("some");
// output:
// false
// true
```

Comment: Все они создают. Просто значение `this` скопится статически (лексически).

Comment: @smellyshovel, удалил первое предложение. Теперь всё правильно? Может я сам чего недопонимаю, а тут с советами лезу)))

Comment: Ну в принципе говорите верно, просто формулировка не совсем точная.

Answer (score 3):

> [[ThisBindingStatus]] - "lexical" | "initialized" |  "uninitialized" -
>   If the value is "lexical", this is an ArrowFunction and does not have
>   a local this value.

[Цитата из спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-function-environment-records).

Если функция является стрелочной, то значение `this` скопится [scopes] статически (то есть лексически). Это значит, что значение `this` внутри стрелочной функции будет таким же, как и в том Лексическом Окружении, в рамках которого определена эта стрелочная функция.

Иными словами, чтобы определить значение `this` внутри стрелочной функции достаточно лишь знать, **каково значение `this` внутри того блока, в котором эта стрелочная функция определена**.

```js
console.log(this);
let this1 = this;

let foo = () => {
    console.log(this);
    let this2 = this;
    
    let bar = () => {
        console.log(this);
        let this3 = this;
        
        let baz = () => {
            let this4 = this;
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this1 === this4); // === this2 === this3
            
        }
        baz();
    }
    bar();
};

foo();
```